# Edit appended text on a div - knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

With knockout.js I am creating new div elements with a button click event. The divs are draggable with the help of jquery ui. I am also able to delete the divs that are created. However, how can I change the appended text of a created div? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/P9C7E/23/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.droppable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).droppable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items(['']);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

HTML

```
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[X]</span><br><br>
        <center><span  data-bind="text:$data"></span></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to edit text ?? I mean on some button click or any other way ?? Or double click on the created span with text it will make the span editable so you can edit the text it in ??

Comment: @Yunus correct double click on a span, similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jr2rE/ but I cant seem to figure it out\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually by adding editable element (for example, `<input>`) to every `<div class="item">` and adding `dblClick` event handler to `<div>` text element (`<span>`) to show `<input>` instead of `<span>`.

To return from editing text to its showing you can use `click` event handler to get back from editable element to plain text element (`<span>`).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9C7E/26/).

HTML:

```
<div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
    <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[X]</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <center>
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span>
        <input class="edit_text"/>
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.edit_text
{
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});
```